# Pytest - Is possible to output test results and print/logging statements while they are executed, instead of waiting for the end of the tests?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a file used to run different unit tests on my application; I am using pytest in a python module to run those tests. All seems fine, except that I get the output only at the end.

As comparison, if I run pytest from terminal via command line, I am able to get some of the output from each tests (minus the print statements, which are printed at the end no matter what); but when I run pytest as library inside a python module, everything stops until all the tests are done.

```
import pytest

#...setup the parameters for the test, prepare everything before call main
pytest.main(parameters)
```

Basically as soon as the `pytest.main` is called, I have to wait for all the tests (in my case 18 tests), to be completed, before I see anything in the output. Why there is such a difference between the command line execution of the same python test module, compared to run pytest via `main` function? And is there a way to have pytest to print the output of each test (including the eventual print statements in the test or functions called by the test), one by one, as they are executed, instead of waiting until the end?
Thanks

Comment: As for your question about printing the output - this is what `pytest -s` shall do.

Comment: As for your main question: `pytest.main` shall do the same as the command line. I just tried it, and it works ok for me (e.g. shows the output while the tests are running). Maybe there is something else in your environment that causes the buffering? Where are you running this?

Comment: Thanks; I basically have one file with subclass of unitTest class for each test; which contains 18 tests. When I run that file with `python3 -m pytest -s myfile.py` it runs fine and each test completed I see either the dot or the F printed, if the test fail. But when I run the same parameters with `pytest.main`, the screen stay blank until all the tests are performed. I call `pytest.main` in a function of a different file called runtests.py, that file just run the tests and has few utility functions but nothing else. I use OSX to run the code as OS

Comment: Sorry -  no idea. I just tested this under Windows (both in the Windows command line and in the bash), and this works as expected: there is no difference between `python myfile.py` and `python -m pytest -s myfile.py` (if adding `if __name__ == '__main__': pytest.main(['-s'])`. Not sure if this is specific to the buffering behavior of the shell you are excuting this in.

Comment: Thanks, I can try on Windows; and see if the behavior is happening only on OSX.